# How to handle errors in Node JS MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, error-handling, callback, try-catch

I have a code in Node JS MySQL to insert some values to a table. I've used callbacks to establish connection and execute MySQL queries. I'm having trouble propagating the errors to catch block if some error occurs.

Please refer to my code

```
 router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    try {
      var category_name = "Books"
      var account_id = "6908vbb465789"
      connection.query(
        "INSERT INTO category(category_name,account_id) Values(?,?)",
        [category_name,account_id],
        function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) {
            throw (error);

          } else {
            res.send({
              code: 200              
            });
          }

        });

    } catch (e) {

      res.status(400).json(e);
    }
  })
```

But if some error occurs, the app crashes and it is not caught inside the catch block. Any solution for this?

Comment: You're throwing inside the callback function, which is called from somewhere else, thus avoiding your try catch. Instead of using throw on error, use the res object to return the desired error response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Celsiuss. Even If I use res. send() to return an error, the app crashes

Comment: Maybe provide the errors? It might not be crashing where you expected.